# Removing unwanted appearance of underlying mesh

Tags: plotting, graphics, mac-os-x, mesh

Let us first define two positive definite matrices:

```
M1 = {{2, -6}, {4, 8}};
M2 = {{2, 3}, {4, 8}};
```

then set two points `p1={-1,-1}` and `p2={1,1}`. Finally we define an anisotropic distance function, namely:

```
d[q1_, q2_, M_] := Sqrt[(q1 - q2).M.(q1 - q2)]
```

When trying to plot the *anisotropic Voronoi cells* as follows:

```
Show[
 Graphics[Point[{p1, p2}]],
 RegionPlot[
  {
   d[{x, y}, p1, M1] < d[{x, y}, p2, M2],
   d[{x, y}, p1, M1] > d[{x, y}, p2, M2]
   },
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}
  ]
 ]
```

I obtain the following image:

[image: Resulting image with unwanted mesh]

My question is: **How can I get rid of the underlying mesh, which is visible in this example?**

Two remarks:

1. Removing the points' plotting also removes the mesh.
2. Adding something like `Mesh->None` to the `RegionPlot` doesn't help.

---

### Edit:

It seems this problem is specific to Mac OS X. Here is the `Options[RegionPlot]` output:

```
{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorOutput -> Automatic, 
 ContentSelectable -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, Epilog -> {}, 
 Evaluated -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None, 
 FormatType :> TraditionalForm, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> {}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> {}, 
 GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> {}, ImageMargins -> 0.`, 
 ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, 
 MaxRecursion -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshShading -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, 
 PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotLabel -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, 
 PlotRegion -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, RotateLabel -> True,
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> Automatic, 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> Automatic, Ticks -> Automatic, 
 TicksStyle -> {}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}
```

Comment: This mesh should not appear by default. Does it appear in other types of graphics, like `DensityPlot` for example? What OS and Mathematica version?

Comment: No mesh when I plot it on M 7.0.1.0, XP SP3

Comment: Just in case: could you please include the result of `Options[RegionPlot]` in your question?

Comment: With no changes in you code, I get the output without mesh lines (Mma v8.0.4 on Vista 64bit). Perhaps, the version you are using or your option settings are causing the problem?

Comment: I get a mesh in Mathematica v8.0.4 on OS X Lion

Comment: I get no mesh in v8.0.4 on Windows.

Comment: Can you please include the operating system and Mathematica version in the question?

Comment: I get a mesh on 8.0.4 on OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are combining the images in the form

```
Show[Graphics[simplePrimitives], complicatedRegionPlot]
```

The options in the resulting figure are inherited from the first term, namely `Graphics[simplePrimitives]`.  This does not include the `"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True` generated by `RegionPlot`.  You see the mesh as a result.  If you combine things as follows:

```
Show[complicatedRegionPlot, Graphics[simplePrimitives]]
```

Then the resulting image will have the standard `RegionPlot` options and you'll no longer see the mesh.

I think the preferred way to do this, however, is to use `Epilog`, as in J.M.'s response.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the mesh shows up in addition to fixing the problem

Comment: What OS are you using?  I see no mesh at all.  I wonder if the mesh is a Mac-only thing.

Comment: The simplest solution in some sense although the others work as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I used V8.0.4 on Mac OS X. I can confirm that V8.0.0 on Windows running in Virtual Machine displays no Mesh.  That's odd.  The inconsistency seems to be a bug to me.

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe graphics rendering is done differently on different platforms (or different modes are enabled by default), and some idiosyncrasy of the Mac rendering forced the developers to use this workaround.  I noticed that @Heike's screenshot is not antialiased.  Antialiasing is missing on Windows only when hardware accelerated rendering is used (this mode is automatically turned on e.g. if a `Polygon` with different `VertexColors` is included, but it's usually off)

Comment: The issue persists with *Mathematica* 10.3.1 under OS X (I'm running El Capitan 10.11.2). It's a shame the behavior depends so greatly upon the platform, as it makes use of a number of graphics functions more complicated -- and harder to explain to novices -- on OS X.

Answer (score 22):

You could use the (undocumented) option `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` for this, e.g.

```
Show[Graphics[Point[{p1, p2}]], 
 RegionPlot[{d[{x, y}, p1, M1] < d[{x, y}, p2, M2], 
   d[{x, y}, p1, M1] > d[{x, y}, p2, M2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}],
 Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
```

which produce

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` is not documented, for `Graphics`, in *Mathematica* 10.3.1 (and possibly in 10.3).

Answer (score 13):

`RegionPlot[{d[{x, y}, p1, M1] < d[{x, y}, p2, M2], d[{x, y}, p1, M1] > d[{x, y}, p2, M2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Epilog -> Point[{p1, p2}]]` seems to do what you want:

[image: RegionPlot[] example]

Comment: On that note: if you just want to tack on simple graphics primitives (e.g. `Point[]`, `Line[]`) to your plots, the use of either the `Prolog` or `Epilog` options looks slightly neater than using `Show[]`.