# Mesh and ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, mac-os-x

Is this a bug, or something going over my head? When using the following code, nothing "special" happens:

```
ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]
```

it works as expected, one gets this graphic, without any mesh lines:

[image]

When adding `Graphics[]` in front of that—as I'd like to `Show` such a `ParametricPlot` with some other graphics, I get this:

```
Show[
 Graphics[],
 ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]
 ]
```

yields:

[image]

Why do those mesh-lines come up? Are those actually Mesh-lines, as I used `Mesh -> None`? How can I delete those lines, while still using `Show` and others `Graphics[]`?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: I've thought that it's because `Show` is taking `Options` from the first element but then I couldn't reproduce your second image. What version are you working on?

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for your fast answer. I'm using Mathematica version 9, I think that's the latest?

Comment: 9.0.1.0. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: No, both codes give me the first result.

Comment: That's strange. Any idea why I get different results?

Comment: works ok on V 9.01, windows 7

Comment: I'm on a mac. Anyone else on a mac having the same problem? Thanks!

Comment: No mesh on linux either.

Comment: try to reboot your mac

Comment: @Nasser: rebooting the system doesn't seem to help...

Comment: I'm using 9.0.1.0 on OS X 10.9 - I see the same problem.

Comment: Try `Show[Graphics[{}, Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True} ], 
 ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]]]` - see [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/removing-unwanted-appearance-of-underlying-mesh) for more...

Comment: @cormullion: this works on my end! Thanks a lot! I don't see this is documented, have I badly looked? Thanks once again!

Comment: I don't think this is documented - I can't find it myself. There are a lot of undocumented things in Mathematica - it wouldn't be so much fun if everything was documented... :)

Comment: I don't this is a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1400/3066). I think it's our old friend `Show` taking it options from its first argument.

Comment: Why not eschew `Show` and just put the graphics in a prolog to `ParametricPlot`?

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem on V9.0.1 running on OS X. I don't think it's a bug. I think it's the old problem of Show taking its options from its first argument. I say this because reversing the order of the arguments fixes the problem.

```
Show[
  Graphics[],
  ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]],
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: plot]

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]],
  Graphics[],
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: So you are agreeing with what @cormullion essentially observed, too. The problem with changing the order of presentation in `Show` is that the purpose of setting `Opacity` in the first place was so that it can be placed on top of a `Graphics` that comes *before* the `RegionPlot`. So changing the order doesn't really seem to be a solution.

Comment: @Jens. Maybe doesn't solve the OP's real problem, but it explains his results. I would advise him to put his graphics in a prolog and eschew `Show`.

Comment: yes, that sounds like the best route. eschew `Show`... Gesundheit.

Comment: eschew...Gesundheit... +1 for the lol (and nice answer, of course).